# React - Snackbar as global component (Typescript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, web, frontend, snackbar

Merry Christmas at first to all of you!

[React + TypeScript]

And yes, I'm a newbie in react, I'm more kind of backend geek, but we all need to learn new stuff :)

I am trying to make my snackbar work in all components globally, to not write a new one every time.

I saw one post about this before: [How to implement material-ui Snackbar as a global function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64754560/how-to-implement-material-ui-snackbar-as-a-global-function)

But unfortunatelly I can't make it work.

Is my function even correct?
And if it is, how can I call it from another component now?

I made this function:

SnackbarHOC.tsx

`

```
import { AlertTitle, IconButton, Snackbar } from '@mui/material';
import Slide from '@mui/material';
import Alert from '@mui/material';
import { useState } from 'react';
import CloseIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Close';

function SnackbarHOC<T>(WrappedComponent: React.ComponentType<T>, Alert: React.ElementType) {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    const [message, setMessage] = useState("I'm a custom snackbar");
    const [duration, setDuration] = useState(2000);
    const [severity, setSeverity] = useState(
        "success"
    ); /** error | warning | info */

    return (props: T) => {


        const showMessage = (message: string, severity = "success", duration = 2000) => {
            setMessage(message);
            setSeverity(severity);
            setDuration(duration);
            setOpen(true);
        };

        const handleClose = (event: React.SyntheticEvent | Event, reason?: string) => {
            if (reason === 'clickaway') {
                return;
            }
        }

        return (
            <>
                <WrappedComponent {...props} snackbarShowMessage={showMessage} />
                <Snackbar
                    anchorOrigin={{
                        vertical: "bottom",
                        horizontal: "center"
                    }}
                    autoHideDuration={duration}
                    open={open}
                    onClose={handleClose}
                //TransitionComponent={Slide}
                >
                    <Alert severity="error"
                        sx={{ width: '100%' }}

                        action={
                            <IconButton
                                aria-label="close"
                                color="inherit"
                                size="small"
                                onClick={handleClose}>
                                <CloseIcon fontSize="inherit" />
                            </IconButton>
                        }>
                        {message}
                    </Alert>
                </Snackbar>
            </>
        );
    };
};

export default SnackbarHOC;
```

`

I tried to call it from another component, but I have no idea how to show the actual snackbar now :(.

It's all that is not giving me errors right now:

`

```
import SnackbarHOC from '../../SnackbarHOC';
```

`

Comment: I'd use Context from react library.

Check this out: https://gist.github.com/akinncar/a9a87537768287fc2c1ed7c7d77d9433

Comment: @JamesG that looks great, not gonna lie. But how to call it then? 
I tried like this, but it's giving me errors:

import { useSnackBar } from '../../SnackBarContext';
...
const mySnackbar = useSnackBar();
...
mySnackbar.showSnackBar('hello', 'info');


error: 
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: mySnackbar.showSnackBar is not a function

Like I said, react is my weakness at now :p

Comment: pls show us how to use it? i'm trying following this https://notistack.com/getting-started but no success

Comment: I found an answer here. It's using JS but nothing that we can't easily translate to TS but it's also not necessary https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Roxf91mp3kw&t=367s

Comment: OK, i got it working from notistack. I had to wrapp all content in app.tsx in <SnackbarProvider>
Thank you guys a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for that but in JS basically, it's the same I guess it's just not typed. I'm implementing within NEXTJS latest

```
//index.jsx
import Head from 'next/head'
import { useState } from 'react';
import {Button} from '@mui/material'
import Notification from '../components/Notification.component'
//create the jsx file with the Snackbar component implemented


function Home() {
// we need a simple hook for the button
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
}
const handleClick = () => {
    setOpen(true);
};
const handleClose = (event, reason) => {
  if (reason === 'clickaway') {
    return;
  }

  setOpen(false);
};
return(
<div >
 <Head>
 <title>HOME</title>
 <meta name="description" content="AWESOME" />
 <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
 </Head>

 <Button variant="outlined" onClick={handleClick}>SEND</Button>
{/*We can define new props for our component I'm mixin props from mui Alert and Snackbar, from Alert I'm using severity and from Snackbar the open and onClose and message goes inside the alert as a simple string :D */}
<Notification
          open={open}
          onClose={handleClose}
          severity="error"
          message="that is what I am talking about"/>
</div>
)

}
```

Now we just need to create the custom component that has multiple lil components inside that we can edit as we want!

```
//Notification.component.jsx file
import React, { forwardRef} from 'react';
import Snackbar from '@mui/material/Snackbar';
import MuiAlert from '@mui/material/Alert';

const Alert = forwardRef(function Alert(props, ref) {
  return <MuiAlert elevation={6} ref={ref} variant="filled" {...props} />;
});

const Notification= ({open, onClose, severity, message}) => {

  
/*<> ... </> The empty tag is shorthand for <React. Fragment>, allowing you to have multiple top-most elements without wrapping further HTML.
*/
  return (

    <>
      
      <Snackbar open={open} autoHideDuration={6000} onClose={onClose}>
        <Alert onClose={onClose} severity={severity} sx={{ width: '100%' }}>
          {message}
        </Alert>
      </Snackbar>
    </>
  );
}
export default Notification;
```

But if you really want use typed values You can check the returned type in your VSCode for each variable and function. but I really don't see any benefit for that. But as it doesn't change the result I will not implement it for me neither here.

I highly recommend to watch this video series https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Roxf91mp3kw&t=367s